# How to use an API

Tags: api, interface, paypal

I'm studying Informatics but somehow I don't get that one.

I want to set up the PayPal NVP-API.
(NVP = Name value Pair).
Can someone tell me how I can CALL an API-Command?
I don't even know which programming language I have to take :S

Reference to the Tutorial: [PayPal NVPAPI Developer Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide.pdf)

Comment: I think you can use any language capable of sending and receiving HTTPS messages. They appear to have tons of how-to material posted that you should check out.

Comment: Yes, they have tons. I checked out pretty everything but they don't even lose one word about how to really call one -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be a bit over your head on this one, but don't worry it's not that difficult.

When they say POST they literally mean an HTTP POST, but since its SSL you'd need to provide credentials also.

jQuery AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ would be a good place to start..

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'paypalurl',
  type : 'POST', //IMPORTANT
  username : 'username',
  password : 'password',
  data : 'YOUR DATA HERE' //form or something of the like
  success : function(r) {
   //handle the success here
  },
  error : function(e) {
   //uh-oh
  }
});
```

This should get you started, but please be careful this is financial data.

Comment: Thanks for this. I always thought they are talking about POST in php and never got that :D

Comment: POST in PHP is what the POST body, sent to the PHP script, contains.
GET would be what is in the GET string, for example www.youwebsite.com/script.php?argn=argv
Where POST[argn] = argv, etc.